# Can DeadLift help me to perform muscleup and press handstand?

Tags: gym, calisthenics, muscle-ups

I love calisthenics, but once i tried to perform a muscle and ended up with an injury in my right shoulder.

Is there any exercise like DeadLift that could help me to do muscle up and press handstand ?

More over for last 2 weeks i have started weight lifting in a gym, and now my shoulder feels better.
i have read a lot of things like to increase my strength right time is in super-compensation period (when i can lift more after recovery).
i am following 3 days full body heavy workout.

Comment: Is this question serious or did you just fail to mention that you are already doing OHP/ HPU with feet on box at 90 degrees, etc for HPU? Also, guess what, your biggest issue with HPU is going to be balance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your definition of a muscle up. A gymnastic muscle up is pure raw power whereas a crossfit muscle-up has a high technique aspect (which can lead to the shoulder issues you mentioned if performed incorrectly).

Deadlift works (almost) everything at a level but primarily works your erectors and your hamstrings while the rest of your body stabilises. The movement required for muscle up requires you to be able to complete 2 specific skills with a transfer.

The movements you want to do are really quite difficult and take technique to do well. Deadlifts alone wont help you get there.

**To train for a RMU**:

1. Ring pull-ups with false grip.
2. Ring dips.
3. Practice transition using a box to support feet (reduce help provided by box slowly.

**To train for a HSPU (handstand push up)**:

1. Start with a supported hand stand (heels against a wall)
2. Shift weight in handstand position to left and right hand
3. Continue 2. but try to remove one hand at a time off the floor.
4. Continue 3 but progress to shoulder taps.
5. Attempt a HSPU but with a support and kip: With a mat for your head that is higher than your hands (higher it is the easier it will be), lower yourself into a headstand. Rest your butt against the wall and bring legs down to your chest, kick up and push up at the same time to kip yourself to the top position.
6. Lower the mat to ground level.
7. Remove the kip
8. Feet off the wall at the bottom
9. Feet completely off the wall
10. Only let head brush the mat.
11. Use paralettes to remove the headstand element.

Answer (score 1):

Muscle-ups and handstands require upper-body strength, which are best built by deadlifts, (overhead) presses, bench presses, chin-ups, and pull-ups.  Muscle-ups also require some neuromuscular explosiveness, the potential for which is dominated by each person's genes.

Muscle-ups and handstands both involve risk of [impingement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impingement_syndrome) of the soft tissues of the shoulder between the humerus and the acromion, so take care to elevate and medially rotate your scapulae during those movements.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlifting, at least for me, is the king of all exercises as it involves the most amount of muscles and increases ones overall body strength.

You also would need some sort of specialization for the execise you want to master so training those movements helps the most. Additional assistence exercises for most demanded body parts can and should be in your arsenal to see even faster results.

I would agree on the previous answer and also would use military press, benching, and dipps would be e good match to tax the upper body part more.

And for the impingement- simply try to touch your ears with your shoulders and keep your elbows in front, while doing military presses... a narrower grip helps here a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It can and will help you, but it certainly isn't necessary to do either of these movements.

During a handstand, you use your fingers and core to stabilize, during a deadlift you strengthen your core a whole bunch, so that will help you to keep your handstand nice and straight. Once you can do a proper handstand, you can move into handstand push-ups. You might want to add in other shoulder exercises like shoulder press to get a bit more strength in the push movement.

As for muscle-ups, it will help you a bit, in the way that you train overall strength of the body with a deadlift, but I'd say there are a lot better movements to train for a muscle-up than the deadlift, it won't contribute as much as doing dips, pull-up variations and negative muscle-ups.

By pull-up variations I mean not only different grips, but also train for explosive pull-ups, do weighted pull-ups, do negative pull-ups. All these things will help you master the bottom part of the muscle-up.

The top part is basically a straight bar dip, so training dips with help you with that. The negative muscle-ups will help you get used to the transition from the dip to the pull-up, try to do this as controlled as possible for mind-muscle connection.

Please don't do a crossfit muscle-up by the way, that's just plain wrong and will only hurt you in the long run.